# Prove a two variable function to be continuos on an specific domain

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let the function $g:D \to \mathbb R^2$ be given by $$g(x,y)=2-|x+y|$$
with domain $D= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2:x+y \leq2\}.$

How to prove it is continuous?

I know that I need to prove this for every element on $D$, so I need to consider an arbitrary element here, but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Dear downvoters, please accompany a downvote with some critique or at least a remark.

Comment: Have you tried working out an epsilon-delta proof for the continuity?

Comment: @MusséRedi No, because i thought it could be "more easy" with just some standard approach.

Comment: Sums, differences, products and compositions of continuous functions are continuous. That shows $g$ is the restriction of a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $D$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I know that, but i dont know if the absolute value is a problem here.

Comment: $\lvert\,\cdot\,\rvert \colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous.